# Selecting rows that are not equal from a different database same server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is it possible for me to compare an specific rows on a different database same server by selecting it? Here are the fields i want to compare.

DB1: UserName and UserPass
DB2: Username and UserPass

What I really want to compare is the USERPASS on both database that are not equal. I added the username Column because it might help to select the UserPass that are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to do this you can do the comparison using fully qualified table names.

To  get a list of all users that have different passwords on the 2 databases. ..

```
Select 
   Db1.username,
   Db1.userpass,
   Db2.userpass
From <databasname1>.dbo. <tablename1> db1
Join <databasename2>.dbo. <tablename2> db2
     On db1.username = db2.username
Where db1.userpass <> db2.userpass
```

Do you need to identify users that only exist in one of the databases.

Comment: Thanks Alan! Sorry been very busy lately. I'll update you once worked. CHeers!